# How to create a program to prompt the user to enter a list, then have the program reverse the list and print it for the user

Tags: python, reverse

How can I create a program to prompt the user to enter a list, then have the program reverse the list and print it for the user. This reversal need to be manual and not use the reverse() function. So far I have ...

```
def main():
    print("This program will reverse your list!")
    list = []
    userlist = input( "Enter your list:")
    list.append(userlist) 
    reverselist = userlist[::-1]
    print("Your list in reverse is: ", reverselist)
    input ("Press enter to close program")
main()
```

It works, but it doesn't keep a list, its more of a string. And if you enter apple banana it spits out ananab elppa.

Comment: Well...`input` can only ever produce a string.  So in that regard it seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Well... It looks like a string because that's what you are reading. It's your job to translate it to a list. Eg., you can use the `split` method from strings for this. Or you can ask each element separately, or...

Comment: So... mylist[::-1] is more "manual" than mylist.reverse()?

Comment: Too bad you have a variable called `list`. Now it's difficult to use the `list()` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    print("This program will reverse your list!")

    # get a list of strings
    items = []
    while True:
        s = input("Next item (or <Enter> to quit): ")
        if s:
            items.append(s)
        else:
            break

    # make a reversed copy of the list
    items_len = len(items)
    smeti = [0] * items_len
    for i,val in enumerate(items)
        smeti[items_len - i - 1] = val

    print("Your list in reverse is: {}".format(smeti))
    input("Press enter to close program")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `smeti` for reversed items! LOL +1

Answer (score 0):

You reversed the string by doing `userlist[::-1]` which is why `banana` is read as `ananab`. What you really should do if split by spaces and reverse the words.

Try changing:

```
userlist = input( "Enter your list:")
list.append(userlist) 
reverselist = userlist[::-1]
```

to:

```
userlist = input( "Enter your list:")
reverselist = " ".join(reversed(userlist.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful 'manual' idiom to reverse a list is a while loop:

```
>>> li
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> il=[]
>>> while li:
...    il.append(li.pop())
... 
>>> il
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

So your program is:

```
def main():
    print("This program will reverse your list!")
    userlist = input( "Enter your list separated by spaces:")
    li=userlist.split()
    reverselist=[]
    while li:
        reverselist.append(li.pop())
    print("Your list in reverse is: ", reverselist)

main()
```

When run:

```
This program will reverse your list!
Enter your list separated by spaces:apple banana peach
Your list in reverse is:  ['peach', 'banana', 'apple']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = []
def reverselyst(list):
    print ("Please enter list values one after the other or press space to stop:")
    while True:
        userinput = input()
        if userinput != ' ':
            list.append(userinput)
        else:
            print (list)
            break
    print("the reverse of list is" + str(list[-1: :-1]))
reverselyst(list)
```